# how to update the list's layout when loader has finished loading

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, loader, getview

I'm using a custom Loader to load data for a listview in a listfragment.
In the listfragment's oncreate method I construct a custom arrayadapter (and call setListAdapter), without passing in any data, because at that time the data has not been loaded yet.
When the loader has finished loading, the fragment gets notified; there I call setData, which is a method in the adapter to add the data to the adapter:

```
public void setData(List<MyInfo> data) {
    clear();
    if (data != null) {
    for (MyInfo item : data) {
    add(item);      }
    }
}
```

I'm pasting this method because I may be missing something here.

When I run the app, the data is loaded allright, setData is executing but the getView method of the adapter never gets called.
However when I remove the TextView with the standard "android:id="@id/android:empty" from my custom layout file, my list is showing up.
I guess the adapter's constructor is inflating the 'empty' textview right in the beginning, before the data has been loaded, and the TextView doesn't get replaced by the ListView once the loader has finished loading.

What should I do to get the 'empty' TextView replaced by the ListView when loading has finished?

Or, maybe this is bad practice - I'm an Android newbie so please forgive me. I want to have the listfragment show at least something, during the first loading, but also when the loaded list is empty. Then what is good practice in this case?

Comment: why not use Progressbar until the data is loaded then use setAdapter?

Comment: Above note is correct, other than that - check out the `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#addAll(java.util.Collection<? extends T>)` method.

Comment: @DamianWalczak thanks for the suggestion, I guess that's more efficient so I changed it.

Comment: @ItzikSamara, thanks for pointing to ProgressBar. I've ended up calling setAdapter and setListShown(false) in the listfragment's onActivityCreated. In onLoadFinished I could use another constructor for the adapter but I thought that it had to be constructed in onActivityCreate. Or would it be better to just call setAdapter in onLoad Finished?